# unnecessary spacing in windows phone keypad. Is this a OS bug?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, appbar, keypad

I came across a rather unusual effect in the `windows phone keypad`, in the `portrait mode`. I have a `textbox` at the `bottom of my grid`, and below it is the `app bar`. Now when the text box gains focus, There is an unnecessary spacing between the `textbox and the keypad`. I have pointed it out in this pic

[image].

Also here is my code,

```
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid Background="PeachPuff" x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollthis">
            <StackPanel x:Name="mystack"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox InputScope="Search" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="myTextBox"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
        aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
        account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
        if the System Tray is hidden.

        Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
    <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="enter text" Click="ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

On app bar click I do the following.

```
    private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock text = new TextBlock() { Text = myTextBox.Text, Margin = new Thickness(0,0,0,5) };
        myTextBox.Text = "";
        mystack.Children.Add(text);
    }
```

If this is an OS bug, should I look for a hack? `Also please note that this spacing is not there in the landscape mode.`

**UPDATE**

I just found out it happens only when there is an `app bar` at the bottom in the portrait mode.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed one more thing, initially even if I handle the grid margins, after entering some text, the spacing starts to grow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which got fixed in GDR 3 Update.

Answer (score 0):

To fix that make your appbar with opacity (0.99 will work) and set bottom margin of ContentPanel to 72 (app bar height).

Comment: Hi, its a hack right? Can you tell me why this is happening? If I use this, there is a bottom margin after the keypad opens which is undesirable.

Comment: Hack or feature, I don't know. Ask MS team for that kind of questions.
You can hide appbar when focusing textbox

Comment: http://imgur.com/wMa2lD5 - if this is okay for you, then manage margin on Got/LostFocus TextBox events
Or consider another layout where textbox is not at the bottom.

Comment: hmm, i cna think of doing that, but i am looking it as a last resort, I want to know how microsoft has implemented its chat bubble? in the sms chat thread, i dnt face problems like this..

Comment: I also noticed one more thing, initially even if I handle the grid margins, after entering some text, the spacing starts to grow.